# Software Center says I'm not authenicated

Tags: software-center

Hi I'm having troubles downloading software from the Ubuntu Software Center. When I click install it says user not authenicated. And I don't have the privilages to do this action. I was wondering how to you get authenticated.
P.S. I am the only user on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the common `Authenticate` dialog window offering to input your user password?

[image]